# Moving file to new location then deleting the Previous file

Tags: java, android, file

I want to move file from one path to another path but instead of moving it copy the file to new location.
Kindly provide any hints

Thanks in advance

```
 MovePngToPreviewDir pngToPreviewDir = new MovePngToPreviewDir(null, "png");

                File[] listOfPNGFiles = RootDir.listFiles(pngToPreviewDir);

                for(File file:listOfPNGFiles){
                    Log.e("PNG = ",file.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.e("PNG = ",file.getName());
                    if(previewDiagramDir == null){
                        Log.e("Preview Diagram Dir is NULL","Preview Diagram DIR is NULL");
                    }
                    if(file!= null && previewDiagramDir != null){
                        Log.e("Preview Diagram Dir",previewDiagramDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/");

                        if(file.renameTo(new File(previewDiagramDir, file.getName()))){
                            Log.e("PNG File is successfully Moved",file.getName());



                        }else{
                            Log.e("Error in Moving PNG File","Error in Moving PNG file");
                        }


                    }else{

                    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to copy the file to another location, you can use `file.renameTo()` method of `File` class, related to your istance object `file`, trying this:

```
file.renameTo(new File("new_directory_to_copy_file"+file.getName()));
```

After copying the file, you can delete it with `file.delete();`.

**Note**: The method `delete()` returns a boolean object, then you can check the correct file deletion with:

```
boolean del = file.delete();

if(del) System.out.println("File "+file.getName()+" deleted!");
else System.out.println("File "+file.getName()+"not deleted!");
```

About the `File` class API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `file.delete()` after the file is copied to another location so that it is completely moved to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved files to the destination directory and after moving deleted those moved files from source folder, in three ways, and at last am using the 3rd approach in my project.

1st approach:

```
File folder = new File("SourceDirectory_Path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
Files.move(Paths.get("SourceDirectory_Path"+listOfFiles[i].getName()), Paths.get("DestinationDerectory_Path"+listOfFiles[i].getName()));
}
System.out.println("SUCCESS");
```

2nd approach:

```
Path sourceDir = Paths.get("SourceDirectory_Path");
Path destinationDir = Paths.get("DestinationDerectory_Path");
  try(DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream =   Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir)){
    for (Path path : directoryStream) {
        File d1 = sourceDir.resolve(path.getFileName()).toFile();
         File d2 = destinationDir.resolve(path.getFileName()).toFile(); 
         File oldFile = path.toFile();
        if(oldFile.renameTo(d2)){
            System.out.println("Moved");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Moved");
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

3rd approach:

```
Path sourceDirectory= Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE_PATH);
        Path destinationDirectory = Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE_MOVE_PATH);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDirectory)) {
            for (Path path : directoryStream) {                                    
                Path dpath = destinationDirectory .resolve(path.getFileName());                                    
                Files.move(path, dpath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();   
        }
```